# How do I find out all modifications made by installing software?

Tags: software, class, operating-systems, dll, installer

So I want to find out how to get a list of all modifications made by installing a piece of software.

For example. If I install Word, I want to see all directories created, classes registered, dlls, 
Modification to drivers. Etc.

Is there a way to do it?

In short I want to know what my OS was before installation, and after; how it differs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a security technology called [file integrity monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring). There are a number of tools that provide it. I'm not going to recommend one because that's explicitly off topic here. But it's good to know what the tech is called.

It basically records hashes for your files and lets you know which ones have been changed. The typical use is intrusion detection but it can also be used to profile installation behavior.